# How is GlyphIndices property encoded in GlyphRun object?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, graphics

I am trying to build a `GlyphRun` object, and I can't seem to understand how `GlyphIndices` property is encoded.

For example, the [following](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms751619%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#drawtext) XAML string creates "hello world". It is obvious that the following rules hold:

- 43 -> h
- 72 -> e
- 79 -> l

But what is this coding scheme? I tried ASCII and it doesn't seem to fit.

Do you have any idea?

---

```
<GlyphRunDrawing ForegroundBrush="Black">
  <GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
    <GlyphRun 
      CaretStops="{x:Null}" 
      ClusterMap="{x:Null}" 
      IsSideways="False" 
      GlyphOffsets="{x:Null}" 
      GlyphIndices="43 72 79 79 82 3 58 82 85 79 71" 
      BaselineOrigin="0,12.29"  
      FontRenderingEmSize="13.333333333333334" 
      DeviceFontName="{x:Null}" 
      AdvanceWidths="9.62666666666667 7.41333333333333 2.96 2.96 7.41333333333333 3.70666666666667 12.5866666666667 7.41333333333333 4.44 2.96 7.41333333333333" 
      BidiLevel="0">
      <GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
        <GlyphTypeface FontUri="C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF" />
      </GlyphRun.GlyphTypeface>
    </GlyphRun>
  </GlyphRunDrawing.GlyphRun>
</GlyphRunDrawing>
```

Comment: The documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.glyphrun.glyphindices) says: "The default value of the glyph indices are defined by the font's character map table for the corresponding *Unicode* code points in the inner text."

Comment: @fmunkert, thanks for your comment. Any idea on how to extract this kind of character map?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this code to convert a Unicode code point to a glyph index:

```
GlyphTypeface glyphTypeface = new GlyphTypeface(new Uri(@"C:\WINDOWS\Fonts\TIMES.TTF"));
const char character = 'и';
ushort glyphIndex;
glyphTypeface.CharacterToGlyphMap.TryGetValue(character, out glyphIndex); 
MessageBox.Show("Index = " + glyphIndex);
```

The sample above returns 610 for the Cyrillic и character.

Comment: Doesn't work for Unicode code points needing 2 chars to store, like .